# Connect RDS Instance in VPC-1 to EKS Cluster of VPC-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, vpc

I have 2 different VPC's in same Region and same AWS Account and let's say 1st VPC is VPC-1
2nd VPC is VPC-2

I have multiple RDS Databases in VPC-1 which have data which is critical.

I have new EKS cluster running in VPC-2. Now i want to my EKS Cluster in VPC-2 to be able to access those RDS instances.

Only Way I could figure out was VPC Peering which I applied and added CIDR-Ranges in Routing tables of both VPC's

Still I am unable to add security group of EKS-Cluster which is in VPC-2 as an in-bound rule in the security group of RDS instance in VPC-1

Any sorts of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the vpc2 (eks) cidr as a source in inbound rule of security group of rds.

I had the same issue some time back with vpc peering where I was connecting the bastion host in one vpc to private ec2 in other vpc . I wasnt able to find the sg of bastion host in inbound roule of sg of private ec2. I resolved the issue by adding the cidr of bastion host vpc.  FYI Thats was my sandbox env.

Comment: Does the CIDR addition require VPC Peering.

P.S i resolved this by taking backup of DB and restoring it in other VPC

Comment: yes the VPC peering is needed for comms between two VPC .

Comment: For all those who have isolated subnets , make sure the access to vpc is allowed via the ACLs also